# Why do we write limit for each term?

Tags: limits

$$ L = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x+4}$$ 
Why do we have to write the limit separately for each term? And when do we have to write like this?

Comment: Can you give some more context as to where this expression came from?

Comment: this expression is from a solved example from my text but i dont know yet how to write it in the proper format

Comment: Right, but what led to this expression - was the previous line "Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x(x+4)}$", for example?

Comment: You don't _have_ to write it like that.

Answer (score 3):

If $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \text{ and } \lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$$ both exist then,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$$

You don't **have** to separate them, however it helps when you notice that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} =1$$

Comment: can you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: @AmmaarSolkar It would probably help Daniel if _you_ explained a bit more, precisely what you're not understanding.

Comment: @AmmaarSolkar $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ is the limit as $x$ goes to $a$ of $f(x)g(x)$. $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ is the limit as $x$ goes to $a$ of $f(x)$, times the limit as $x$ goes to $a$ of $g(x)$. Daniel's saying that these are equal to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we have to write the limit separately for each term?

This is simple manipulation. Helps in calculating the limit. Eases the job of finding the limit.

> And when do we have to write like this?

In general, we write $$\lim_{x\to a}\{f(x)\cdot g(x)\} = \{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\} \cdot \{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\}$$ if and only if $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$ both separately exist.

Answer (score 0):

If two sequences (or functions) have a finite limit, then so does the product of the sequences/functions and the limit is the product of the individual limits. This is a consequence (almost the definition) of the continuity of multiplication, considered as a mapping from $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to break a single complicated glob into several smaller pieces that are easier to deal with individually, then recombine the separate answers into a single answer. "Divide and conquer" as they say.

Note there is some skill involved, because you have to separate the factors in a way that is helpful. For example, If you have to evaluate the limit of $$\frac{\sin x}{x(x+4)}$$
as $x\to0$, it is very helpful to regroup the expression as $$\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x+4}\right)$$ but not very helpful at all to regroup it as
$$\left(\frac{\sin x}{x+4}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
Can you see why?